# List of items with last Shipment Date

Tags: sql, max, getdate

I'm trying to get a list of items in stock for an order, with the latest confirmed leadtime given by our supplier. If I try to use the Query like this it will return every leadtime ever confirmed for that item. How do I get it to only show me the last one?

```
SELECT  

T0.DocNum AS Order,  
T1.ItemCode AS Item,  
T2.U_Internal_Code AS IntItem,  
CAST (((T2.onhand+T2.OnOrder)-T2.IsCommited) as int) AS Stock,  
T3.ShipDate

FROM 

ORDR T0

INNER JOIN RDR1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry   
INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode  
INNER JOIN POR1 T3 ON T2.U_Bestelcode = T3.U_Bestelcode

WHERE T0.DocNum='1234' AND T3.ShipDate=(SELECT MAX (ShipDate) FROM POR1 WHERE T3.ShipDate = ShipDate)

ORDER BY T1.ItemCode
```

Comment: Order then in a descending order and only pick the first one(The way might change depending on your database software)

Comment: `T3.ShipDate=(SELECT MAX (ShipDate) FROM POR1 WHERE T3.ShipDate = ShipDate)` makes no sense to me. Shouldn't it read  kind of `.. FROM POR1 t4 WHERE T4.U_Bestelcode = t3.U_Bestelcode'

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Top 1 selects only one row which is at top. İf you write TOP 2 you can get 2 data from top.

For SQL

```
SELECT TOP 1

T0.DocNum AS Order,  
T1.ItemCode AS Item,  
T2.U_Internal_Code AS IntItem,  
CAST (((T2.onhand+T2.OnOrder)-T2.IsCommited) as int) AS Stock,  
T3.ShipDate

FROM 

ORDR T0

INNER JOIN RDR1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry   
INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode  
INNER JOIN POR1 T3 ON T2.U_Bestelcode = T3.U_Bestelcode

WHERE T0.DocNum='1234' AND T3.ShipDate=(SELECT MAX (ShipDate) FROM POR1 WHERE T3.ShipDate = ShipDate)

ORDER BY T1.ItemCode DESC;
```

For MySQL

```
SELECT

    T0.DocNum AS Order,  
    T1.ItemCode AS Item,  
    T2.U_Internal_Code AS IntItem,  
    CAST (((T2.onhand+T2.OnOrder)-T2.IsCommited) as int) AS Stock,  
    T3.ShipDate

    FROM 

    ORDR T0

    INNER JOIN RDR1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry   
    INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1.ItemCode = T2.ItemCode  
    INNER JOIN POR1 T3 ON T2.U_Bestelcode = T3.U_Bestelcode

    WHERE T0.DocNum='1234' AND T3.ShipDate=(SELECT MAX (ShipDate) FROM POR1 WHERE T3.ShipDate = ShipDate)

    ORDER BY T1.ItemCode DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: The question asked for the last date for *each* item.

Answer (score 0):

By filtering on  `WHERE T3.ShipDate = ShipDate` you're going to get a different date for each row in T3.

I think you want something like `WHERE T3.Vendor= Vendor` to find the latest date for the vendor in total

Obviously dependent on your DB structure.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
WHERE T0.DocNum='1234' AND T3.ShipDate=(SELECT MAX (ShipDate) FROM POR1 WHERE T3.ShipDate = ShipDate)
ORDER BY T1.ItemCode
```

to this

```
WHERE T0.DocNum='1234'
ORDER BY T3.ShipDate DESC, T1.ItemCode
limit 1
```

Comment: The question asked for the last date for *each* item.

Comment: I've tried this with the TOP 1 function (Because SQL and not MySQL), but this doesn't solve my problem, it now only shows 1 item instead of the list (58 items in my case)